# Html table cell to wrap text without extending height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following table for which I'd like to set cell heights and widths determined by provided dimensions. It works fine as long as the cell content does not wrap on its own. In the image, the first row is meant to be 20px high, but the orange content extends the row height beyond the 20px. It would work fine, if the `white-space` was set to `nowrap` (as for the top/left cell).

However, I would like the text to wrap, but it should be cut off where it would go beyond the designated row height (similar to how the text it cut off to the right when it would go beyond the width).

Is that possible and how would I be able to achieve that?

[image]

```
<html>

<body>

<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 200px'>

  <colgroup width='50'></colgroup>
  <colgroup width='50'></colgroup>
  <colgroup width='20'></colgroup>
  

  <tr style='height: 20px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>

    <td style='background-color: olive; display: table-cell; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;'>
      Very long text
    </td>

    <td style='background-color: orange; display: table-cell; overflow: hidden;'>
      <span style='white-space: normal;'>
        I want this text to wrap, yet not to expand the height of the cell/row
      </span>
    </td>

    <td style='background-color: steelblue; display: table-cell'>
      Fooo barrrr
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='background-color: aliceblue;'>
      <span>
        Blablub
      </span>
    </td>
    <td style='background-color: aqua;'>
      <span>
        Long text
      </span>
    </td>
    <td style='background-color: aquamarine; display: table-cell; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>
      Another text
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

I've got somewhat of a solution, but it requires the height to be set in the cell itself which I'd like to avoid (ideally, the height should be set by `<tr>`). I applied `display: inline-block; height: 20px` to the span of the orange cell:

```
      <span style='white-space: normal; display: inline-block: height: 20px'>
        I want this text to wrap, yet not to expand the height of the cell/row
      </span>
```

Comment: It is mathematically impossible for the text to wrap without increasing the cell height when the cell is restricted to 20px and the text is 16px.

Comment: It should wrap, but the result should be cut off, just like when something is rendered with `overflow: hidden`. I want the height to determine how much of the wrapped content is shown (increasing it, will show more of the wrapped text, but the wrapped text shouldn't determine the height of the cell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values for `td` overrule the declarations on the `tr`. The overflow declaration is not inherited and the height declaration is equivalent to min-height.

Use these declarations for the `td`:
`display: block; height: inherit; white-space: normal;`

---

This example shows how to use CSS for the deprecated HTML attributes `cellspacing`, `cellpadding`, and `width`. The widths that you used for the `colgroup`s add up to 120px but the table is 200px, so the browser has to calculate how to expand the colgroups to fit. I've substituted the calculated values in this example.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 200px;
  }

td {
  padding: 0;
  }

colgroup {
  width: 83.33px;
  }

colgroup:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 33.34px;
  }
```

```html
<table>

  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  

  <tr style='height: 20px; white-space: nowrap;'>

    <td style='background-color: olive; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;'>
      Very long text
    </td>

    <td style='background-color: orange; overflow: hidden; display: block; height: inherit; white-space: normal;'>
        I want this text to wrap, yet not to expand the height of the cell/row
    </td>

    <td style='background-color: steelblue;'>
      Fooo barrrr
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style='background-color: aliceblue;'>
      <span>
        Blablub
      </span>
    </td>
    <td style='background-color: aqua;'>
      <span>
        Long text
      </span>
    </td>
    <td style='background-color: aquamarine; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>
      Another text
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```